Is there a way to improve start performance with websphere liberty application?
There are about 40 applications start up. And the start performance is very slow. By flame diagram analysis, the application dynamicImport-Package is * which slow the start process.
Product version: 23.0.0.11
Application Type: WarApplication
<featureManager>
     <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
     <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
     <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
     <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
     <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
     <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

How can I perf this problem? Is there any way to perf the start process?

When many applications start simultaneously, they will compete for resources and contention at bottleneck points (e.g. a common archive file containing classes shared among the apps) may slow down the start process. If that is the problem, you may be able to reduce contention by sequencing app startup, rather than having them all try to start at once. This can be done with the "startAfterRef" configuration attribute in Liberty, described in this doc.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=configuration-webapplication
Of course there are other reasons that a configuration with 40 apps would start slowly, such as system CPU limits, system memory limits, insufficient Java heap, etc. But if you have already made sure those basic resource issues are not the problem, then "startAfterRef" may be helpful.

Thanks for your answer. I try this way but didn't work. Are there any way else to improve start performance? Including start speed and memory consumption?

What do you mean by "didn't work"? Do you mean that the apps still tried to start all-at-once? Or they started in the sequence you configured, but start performance did not improve? Or some other outcome which falls under the umbrella of "didn't work"?
Does your environment provide enough resources to start 40 apps? Some experiments may help answer that question. For example: If you configure just one app, how long does that take to startup? Then with five apps, how long does that take? Then with 10 apps, how long does that take? Then with 40 apps, how long does that take to start?
